# How to get the filtered items alone from webpage using selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In this website https://rahulshettyacademy.com/seleniumPractise/#/. I filtered vegetables starting with CA and trying to get only displayed filtered items from the page. if I try the locators manually after the filter is giving only 4 instances same as if try with the script it is taking all the 30 items from the DOM.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='search']").send_keys("ca")  #SearchBox   
veg_name = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.products-wrapper div h4") # filtered Items   
print(len(veg_name))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to add some delay (wait) after sending the text to search input and get the amount of displayed results after that.
1 second delay will be more than enough.

To do it more correct but by the longer code you can and

```
wait.until((ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(element)))
```

where `element` is locator of product that should disappear in your search
just add some short delay after that case to insure all the other irrelevant elements disappeared too.

Comment: Implemented time.sleep(20). now it's successfully getting the filtered items count

Comment: So if my answer helped you please accept it